# ruby select element nested hash same keys

Tags: ruby, hash

I have the hash below from which I'm trying to get "value" of the element matching '"year" => "2014"' and '"period" => "M06"'.

```
result = {"status"=>"REQUEST_SUCCEEDED", "responseTime"=>28, "message"=>[], "Results"=>{"series"=>[{"seriesID"=>"LNU03034342", "data"=>[{"year"=>"2014", "period"=>"M06", "periodName"=>"June", "value"=>"11.1", "footnotes"=>[{}]}, {"year"=>"2014", "period"=>"M05", "periodName"=>"May", "value"=>"16.8", "footnotes"=>[{}]}, {"year"=>"2014", "period"=>"M04", "periodName"=>"April", "value"=>"18.8", "footnotes"=>[{}]}, {"year"=>"2014", "period"=>"M03", "periodName"=>"March", "value"=>"18.7", "footnotes"=>[{}]}, {"year"=>"2014", "period"=>"M02", "periodName"=>"February", "value"=>"17.6", "footnotes"=>[{}]}, {"year"=>"2014", "period"=>"M01", "periodName"=>"January", "value"=>"16.0", "footnotes"=>[{}]}]}]}}
```

So far I have 'result["Results"]["series"][0]["data"]' which yields:

```
{"year"=>"2014", "period"=>"M06", "periodName"=>"June", "value"=>"11.1", "footnotes"=>[{}]}
{"year"=>"2014", "period"=>"M05", "periodName"=>"May", "value"=>"16.8", "footnotes"=>[{}]}
{"year"=>"2014", "period"=>"M04", "periodName"=>"April", "value"=>"18.8", "footnotes"=>[{}]}
{"year"=>"2014", "period"=>"M03", "periodName"=>"March", "value"=>"18.7", "footnotes"=>[{}]}
{"year"=>"2014", "period"=>"M02", "periodName"=>"February", "value"=>"17.6", "footnotes"=>[{}]}
{"year"=>"2014", "period"=>"M01", "periodName"=>"January", "value"=>"16.0", "footnotes"=>[{}]}
```

Now, all the keys in each element of this parent hash are the same, so I'll need to get what I want by searching period for M06, select that element, then get value from the element.  How do I do this?

I realize that technically I could take the first of the nested hashes since I'm seeking the highest period, but that seems sloppy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do as

```
result["Results"]["series"][0]["data"].find(->(){ {} }) do |hash|
    hash[period] == 'M06'
end.fetch(value, "period not found")
```

> [`#find`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) - Passes each entry in enum to block. Returns the first for which block is not false. *If no object matches, calls ifnone* and returns its result when it is specified, or returns nil otherwise.

Thus for any reason if `'M06'` value not found for the key *period* from any of the *hash*, then the `#find` will call the *argument* I passed to it, like `->() { {} }.call`, and return the *empty hash*, otherwise if `'M06'` found for the key `'period` of any hash,then that *hash* will be returned. On this returned *hash*, I am calling [`Hash#fetch`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Hash.html#method-i-fetch) method.

Example to explain this :-

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

array = {a: 1, b: 2}, { a: 4, b: 11}

def fetch_value(array, search_key, search_value, fetch_key)
  array.find(->(){ {} }) do |h|
    h[search_key] == search_value 
  end.fetch(fetch_key, "#{search_value} is not found for #{search_key}.")
end

fetch_value(array, :a, 11, :b) # => "11 is not found for a."
fetch_value(array, :a, 4, :b) # => 11
```

Comment: I see that this works, thank you.  I don't quite follow what `->(){ {} }` does, however.  Do you mind elaborating?

Comment: @UserDuser That is a `Proc` object, I created it using using *staby operator*.. this is same as `lambda() { {} }`.. Is this now clear ? The proc object contains an *empty hash (`{}`)*, which will be returned, when you call the *proc object*.